# Issues with Doctrine Versionable (Audit Log) Behavior

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, versioning

Im using the Doctrine versionable behavior for one of my models. The schema works fine & tables are created. But when I try to load fixtures for this, I get a fatal error saying `class TaxCodeVersion not found`. I checked my Model dir, and indeed the class TaxCodeVersion is not generated by Doctrine. I always use the `build --all --no-confirmation` command. Am I missing on something?

```
TaxCode:
  package: Taxes
  tableName: Fin_Tax_Codes
  actAs:
    Activateable: ~
    SoftDelete: ~
    Versionable:
      tableName: fin_tax_codes_version
      versionColumn: version
      className: %CLASS%Version
      auditLog: true
    Auditable: ~
    Timestampable: ~
    Multitenant: ~
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: true
.....other columns.....
```

Comment: and this class is demanded by the AuditLog Listener

Comment: Try remove a package and build the model. I noticed different behavior (might be it's a bug).

Comment: Hey Kuba, I just tried doing that this morning. Removing package doesn't help at all.
All I am sure is that I do not see the model class for version table anywhere!

Should I log a bug?

Comment: I tried a manual workaround by defining the model class for the Version class, and it works.
Have logged a bug: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've logged a bug here: [Pl go thru it and vote if it affects you](http://doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-839)

If you can't live without this, then you can carefully set-up the model schema for the version class by manually creating a class file in the model directory and its parent in the base directory.
Make sure that there are no relations on the version table, all unique indexes need to be dropped.

Comment: Sadly no one is voting for the bug on Doctrine Jira. This way the bug will never get priority. If anyone has found a solution by modifying code, please share the solution!